# webview from json string loadurl() android

Tags: android, json, android-studio, webview, android-webview

i want to load url for webview from my json string. but i don't understanding what i need to do for that. i'm trying to load url using `getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_img");` but it's not working. how i can do that? i have json data for the url. here i want to load this image url in webview to open Webview Client.

JSON Data:

```
image: "https://website.com/library/2019/11/03/1572813810_6.jpg"
```

my code is:

```
        mainWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebclient());
        mainWebView.loadUrl(getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_img"));

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

        // Recieve data
        String webview  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_img");

        TextView tv_name = findViewById(R.id.aa_anime_name);

        // setting values to each view
        tv_name.setText(webview);
```

how i can load the webview url from my `json` data?

Comment: please help me experts.

Comment: it's showing `Expression Expected` while i'm replacing `setWebViewClient(webSettings)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you send to in anime_img key? Is the " https://website.com/library/2019/11/03/1572813810_6.jpg "data returning?

So why do you show it in webview? You can display it using libraries such as Glide, Picasso in Imageview. Show this libraries. [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) , [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

If you say, I'll show it on webview.

```
    // Recieve data
    String webviewUrl  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_img");

    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      mainWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

    mainWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(webSettings);
    mainWebView.loadUrl(webviewUrl);
```

You can'll try this.

Comment: it's showing `Expression Expected` while i'm replacing `setWebViewClient(webSettings)`

Comment: i have `public class myWebclient extends WebViewClient {//code here}`. so must need to `setWebViewClient(webSettings);` with `myWebclient`. can you please check your answer again and if need please edit.

Answer (score 0):

after adding this code my problems has been solved :)

```
String webviewUrl  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_img");
mainWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebclient());
mainWebView.loadUrl(webviewUrl);

WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mainWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
```

special thanks to *fevziomurtekin*